# This type ... does not support changes ... from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread - despite using CheckAccess

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

Consider the following (simplified) code in a custom collection class I wrote:

```
public class ObservableConcurrentCollection<T> : IObservableConcurrentCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableConcurrentCollection( )  
    {
        _context = Application.Current?.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void _notify() //This may be called from any thread
    {
        if (_context.CheckAccess())
        {
            _invokeCollectionChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            _context.InvokeAsync(() => _invokeCollectionChanged(), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        }
    }

    private void _invokeCollectionChanged() //This is only expected to be called from the main/UI thread
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

I get the infamous "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread" exception when raising the event. Why? Is `CheckAccess` not reliable? When the exception fires, Visual Studio says I'm on the main/UI thread...

Any ideas where to look?

EDIT: The thing is that the code runs fine 99.99% of the time, just once in a very seldom while it crashes. I've gone through the general sync'ing mechanism here on SO and elsewhere and it appears to be fine.

It's as if there's some kind of race condition - but I wouldn't know who's running...

Comment: I would imagine that the collection assumes you're calling from another thread because you're using Invoke rather than calling the method directly as you normally would from the same thread.

Comment: Did you try using [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) method?